# VBA to return parent folder within a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I had this code cracked and saved within my Excel but stupidly lost it upon a re-install of windows.
I am rubbish with VBA & remember it took me quite some time to find this solution.
I have spent the afternoon/evening looking for the post where I got the code from but cannot find it.

I need a VBA/Macro to display the parent folder name into a chosen cell.

Please help!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean the path of the current Workbook?

Comment: In what format do you need the parent folder?  For example, do you need something like `C:\Temp\Path\Workbook1.xlsx` or `C:\Temp\Path` or do you simply need `Path`?

Comment: It is simply just `path` thanks.

Comment: Although learning the others will probably be helpfull in the future!

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
Public Function GetPath() As String
    GetPath = Right(ThisWorkbook.Path, Len(ThisWorkbook.Path) - InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\"))
End Function
```

Paste this code into a module in your workbook. Then in the cell you choose use the formula:
`=GetPath()`

Comment: Hi thanks for the codes. This code works but my problem is once I have completed my workbook it gets saved into a different folder. This code always shows the current folder name. I need it to enter in as a value not a formula so then when the file is moved the original value remains.

Comment: You can copy it and then paste values over it.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a hack, but...

```
Sub WorkbookParentDirectory()
  Dim x() As String
  x = Split(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\")
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = x(UBound(x) - 1)
End Sub
```

Here is the function version of above:

```
Public Function WorkbookParentDirectory()
  Dim x() As String
  x = Split(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\")
  WorkbookParentDirectory = x(UBound(x) - 1)
End Function
```

In the cell you want the Parent Directory shown type `=WorkbookParentDirectory()`

Comment: Seems to just return Excel. I have saved to other paths but still only Excel. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `Parent` of the directory the file is seved in? Would you prefer a function that you can can call from the cell?

Comment: Basicly I have lots of checklist to complete all of which ask for job number. The job number is always the folder name. So a macro to extract the containing folder name would save me having to enter it in on several excel files.

Comment: `jbarker2160's` code gets you the workbook's folder name. My code gives you the workbook's folder's parent folder name.

Comment: I am logged off the PC now but will try both in the morning. As long as the values that are entered are just text and will not change if the excel file is moved these codes will be perfect. The files will be filed in different locations once the jobs is complete. These files will most probably have different folder names but the values I enter must remain. I will have a proper test tomorrow. Thanks for all your replies.

Comment: If you need the folder the excel file is in, and not the parent folder, just remove the `-1` from the code above. Let us know how it goes in the morning.

Comment: Hi tbur. Your code at the top is exactly what I need. But as you asked is it the parent folder or workbook folder I need. Its the workbook folder i need. I have tried to have a mess around with the code & managed to get it to work. `Sub WorkbookParentDirectory()
  Dim x() As String
GetPath = Right(ThisWorkbook.Path, Len(ThisWorkbook.Path) - InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\"))
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = GetPath
End Sub`

Comment: Thanks for both your replies!

Comment: Sorry to keep going on & on but if i wanted to only show the first 5 characters of the workbook folder name how would i go about this?